# Recording from a browsers in background

Tags: windows, video, web-browser, video-recording

Here is the context first:

I have two instances of the internet browser opened. Each one has a video running. One I'm actually watching and the other one I would be recording to watch later.

I tried to use Cyberlink Screen Recording 2 but whenever I switch browsers, it records whatever is in the front.

I need a software that is able to record the video from the browser that I selected (started to record). Once I switch to another browser, it will keep recording from the browser in the background and not the one in the foreground that I'm currently watching.

Is there any software that does that?

Thanks everybody in advance!

NOTE: Already tried all Chrome addons.

NOTE2: Windows 7 or 10.

Comment: Welcome!  What operating system(s)?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following.

1. Download VirtualBox
2. Set up a Virtual Machine with the OS of your preference, please check if you have the rights licenses to do so.
3. Record the screen on the Virtual Machine from Within the Virtual Machine and minimize it.

Please make sure that the output file is being saved somewhere with enough free space.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! I thought about that but I was looking for a simple 1 application solution than a 20Gb (linux) to 60Gb (windows) solution. Today I just need to record 1 screen, but I may need later to record more than one, so that solution would not fix the problem.